# ' Div Wrapper ' Issue

Tags: css

I am wanting to wrap all my content within a div wrapper. I want my content to be wrapped within a div wrapper that's width is 1040px. The problem is, I want the navigation bar to have a with of 100% so that it spans ones screen/ full resolution. By the way, the navigatioon bar will be below the header.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Put the navigation bar outside the wrapper?

Comment: Here are some horizontal list examples: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

here is solution http://jsfiddle.net/YeruE/